# How much memory need osm2po for loading 10Gb map?

Tags: osm2po, memory

i'm using osm2po as routing engine,and i'm trying to load whole europe map ( about 10 GB file ) - java always die on memory error. 
How osm2po works, do i need to have over 10GB of physical memory to make it working or is there any trick for it ? :)

thanks

m.

Comment: Are you referring to RAM on the client machine or the server machine? You might also look into not loading all of the data at full scale at once.  Setting up scale dependencies could improve performance substantially if osm2po supports it.

Comment: Server memory, client is json based html5 application. If i will remove all not routable stuff from it its 20 - 30% smaller which is still very big if osm2po is using 1:1 memory for map.

Answer (score 2):

Well, currently osm2po caches lots of stuff into memory in order to make subsequent routing calls fast. But it doesn't cache everything by default. Usually it reads about half the gph-file into memory. In case of Germany.osm this is about 260 MB.
But it also depends on the street types you are going to include. If you want to include cycle ways and paths the size and memory usage may increase a lot.
Nevertheless, I haven't understood your question entirely. Did you mean the conversion or the routing? I usually test europe.osm on an old 3Gig-Hz/2Gig-RAM box and it is possible to convert it even on this hardware. Please look at the examples on the web page how this can be achieved.

Comment: I'm starting osm2po with this command:

java -Xmx1024m -jar osm2po-core-4.7.7-signed.jar prefix=hh tileSize=x /usr/src/europe-latest.osm.pbf  

and it die during start at line 
.. of .. nodes extracted.

Comment: Here is exact error: 
  FATAL  Exception at Thu Jun 27 17:34:20 CEST 2013
       Message: Increase Java Heap Space: -Xmx
       Class: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       Stacktrace:
       de.cm.osm2po.converter.TileManager$1.next(TileManager.java:432)
       de.cm.osm2po.converter.TileManager$1.next(TileManager.java:411)
       de.cm.osm2po.converter.Joiner.run(Joiner.java:175)
       de.cm.osm2po.Main.runJoiner(Main.java:191)
       de.cm.osm2po.Main.main(Main.java:126)

and here is link to full output: http://pastebin.com/2UbXE6f6

Comment: Indeed, this is too low. -Xmx1024m is only one Gig which is not enough for entire europe. Please look at the examples at http://osm2po.de. There you'll find calls like this one: `java -Xmx1408m -jar osm2po-xxx.jar prefix=eu tileSize=10x10,1,c europe.osm.pbf`

Answer (score 0):

For the European car network I use -Xmx8000m (8 gigs) and option tileSize=x . Not sure if "c" tileSize would decrease perfs

Comment: 8Gig is definetily too much for small boxes. Well, if you want to include paths, pedestrians', cycleways for whole Europe this might be a realistic value if you want to convert it in one piece. But one of the advantages of osm2po is the ability to convert tiles and to finally merge them together. This allows conversions of continents, even on old computers with little RAM. Setting tilesSize=x,c is a nice feature, which is indeed a bit slower but needs less memory in the second conversion phase.

Comment: i try to read it from manual but i do not understand what exactly is tileSize parameter affecting ? Routing ? Or we are speaking about graphic tiles  ? thanks :)

Comment: It affects the conversion. osm2po is no rendering tool.

Comment: But what does digit value for tileSize param mean? (sorry, my level of German does not allow to understand it clearly from manual distributed with osm2po).

Comment: Reading the documentation here...
http://osm2po.de/ > help > program 
...it seems that the tile size is in degrees. So a tileSize parameter of 3x3,0.1 should give tiles 3 degrees by 3 degrees with an overlap of 01. degrees for edges that cross the border of the tiles. I think. 

tileSize=x means NO tiling which will be the hardest on memory.